# How to use multiple SVM classifiers -each with a specific kernel- as a "one vs rest classification" scheme?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

Suppose we have samples of 5 different classes like A, B, C, D and E. In my case, to use a "one vs rest classification" method there has to be 5 one-vs-rest SVM classifiers, something like below:

SVM1: A vs rest

SVM2: B vs rest

SVM3: C vs rest

SVM4: D vs rest

SVM5: E vs rest

These 5 classifiers are trained with training samples and different kernels are used for each classifier. New incoming sample is passed to each of the 5 classifiers to be classified. Then consider a situation when a new sample actually belonging to the category "A" is classified as a memebr of "A" by the SVM1 (which is correct) and at the same time it is classified as a member of "D" by the SVM4 (which is NOT correct), the problem is how to find out which of these two SVMs are predicting correctly. I know there has to be some sort of criterion to compare the prediction confidence of these two.
I am using opencv 2.4.8 and through the syntax below it can predict the label of the class that new sample belongs to:

```
float Response = SVM.predict(new_test_sample,false);
```

I am also aware that there's an option to find out how far is the new sample from the SVM decision boundary, throgh the following syntax :

```
float Distanc = SVM.predict(test, true);
```

Since I am using different kernels and also different parameters for each SVM classifier (and so I know I can't compare prediction confidences by simply comparing the distances to the decision margins...), my question is that how can I compare the prediction confidences of the classifiers so that I can finally know which class does the new sample belong to?
thanks all

Comment: Hi @rayryeng ...Do you have any idea???

Comment: use a 6th class: "UNKNOWN" for ambiguous results

Comment: hi..thanks.. @Micka actually there are 4 classes of objects and the 5th class consists of the rest of the objects...anyway do you have any idea how can I perform a suitable "one-vs-rest" classification using different svm kernels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you usually do in such case is you use Platt's scaling. Efficiently, it simply fits logistic regression on top of your decision functions, to "calibrate" you  estimates, so they are comparable. As an effect, you get a probability estimates P(y|x) for each classifier, which can be now compared across multiple models.

OpenCV in general is quite bad source of classifiers, I would consider using actual ML package instead, which gives you access to such standard tools. In particular libsvm, which OpenCV wraps around - has this feature.

Comment: hey @lejlot thanks I started to use libsvm in matlab currently....another question...I realized there can be one other case...suppose two of the classifiers vote for their type and we have to see the probability values to get the final result between  the 2 classifiers..... what if they both result the same probabilty values for what they have voted ? what else can be done to get the final vote???

Comment: I probably have to reject those samples??

Comment: Nothing, you assign label at random then.